# possible etymologies and cognates for Dutch 'mooi'?

Tags: historical-linguistics, germanic-languages, cognates, dutch, substrate

The Dutch word 'mooi' (beautiful) doesn't seem to have a clear etymology nor any cognates. Does anyone have theories or ideas for possible origins or cognates?

It seems to have caused Dutch 'schoon' to shift from 'beautiful' to 'clean', when compared to Flemish Dutch 'schoon' still having that meaning and German 'schön'.

I think it was already attested in Old Dutch, so perhaps it's of substrate origin? 
Anyway, I'm curious to hear your ideas.
Anyway

http://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/mooi

Answer (score 4):

[Wiktionary has](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mooi#Dutch) a rather plausible etymology of *mooi*:

> From Middle Dutch *moy*, from Old Dutch **mōi** (“nice, pleasant, clean”), from Proto-Germanic **mawjaz* (“clean, washed”), from Proto-Indo-European **mou-io-* (“washed”), from Proto-Indo-European **mū-*, **mew(ə)-* (“to wash, wet”). Cognate with Middle Low German *moie* (“nice, sheen”) (Low German *moi* (“pretty, good, nice”)), Middle Low German *mūten* (“to wash the face”), and possibly to Latin *mundus* (“clean, neat, elegant”).

Comment: I think the link given to http://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/mooi is much more useful than wikipedia.